# Why is mysql caching the column names of a temporay table that is deleted?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've reduced my issue down to this simple SP. The column names are getting cached in the SELECT * at the end. I have no idea why or how to stop it. I tried adding SQL_NO_CACHE but that makes no difference.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
CREATE TABLE foo(
col1 int,
col2 int);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1,2),(3,4),(5,6);
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mysp;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE mysp(c INT)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydata;

   SET @mycol='col1';

   IF c > 0 THEN SET @mycol:='col2';
   END IF;

   SET @s=CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mydata AS SELECT ', @mycol, ' FROM foo');
   PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- The following select call fails on 2nd and subsequent executions of the SP
   SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM mydata;
   SELECT "Please see new temp table mydata" as Result;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Version

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.15-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

First run works fine as expected

```
mysql> CALL mysp(0);
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    5 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.17 sec)

+----------------------------------+
| Result                           |
+----------------------------------+
| Please see new temp table mydata |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.17 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)
```

Now if I try and run it again using the other column

```
mysql> CALL mysp(1);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'qlgqp1.mydata.col1' in 'field list'
mysql> SELECT @mycol;
+--------+
| @mycol |
+--------+
| col2   |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I recreate the storedprocedure again its works

```
mysql> CALL mysp(1);
+------+
| col2 |
+------+
|    2 |
|    4 |
|    6 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.18 sec)

+----------------------------------+
| Result                           |
+----------------------------------+
| Please see new temp table mydata |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.18 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
```

But if I try switching back to the first column - even if I try dropping the temp table first - it still doesn't work

```
mysql> CALL mysp(0);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'qlgqp1.mydata.col2' in 'field list'
mysql> DROP TABLE mydata;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CALL mysp(0);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'qlgqp1.mydata.col2' in 'field list'
mysql>
```

**Additional info asked for by eggyal. Also I tried this on another mysql version with same result. **

```
mysql> CALL mysp(1);
+------+
| col2 |
+------+
|    2 |
|    4 |
|    6 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.20 sec)

+----------------------------------+
| Result                           |
+----------------------------------+
| Please see new temp table mydata |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.20 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> describe mydata;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col2  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL mysp(0);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test.mydata.col2' in 'field list'
mysql> describe mydata;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Interesting development of a fix  - changing the last few lines to a prepared statement works - but using exactly the same query as before.

```
-- The following select call fails on 2nd and subsequent executions of the SP
   PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM mydata';
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   SELECT "Please see new temp table mydata" as Result;
```

Comment: Is that error really coming from that SP?  Could you show the content of `mydata` after each call to the SP?

Comment: Added. I am beginning to suspect the MySQL client caching something.

Comment: Okay, so the `*` is clearly being expanded prior to the execution of the prepared statement (probably upon invocation of the SP).  I don't suppose defining the procedure with the `MODIFIES SQL DATA` characteristic makes any difference?  Nor qualifying the `*` as `mydata.*` or calling `FLUSH TABLES mydata` beforehand?  If not, you could either perform the `SELECT` via another prepared statement (as suggested by @spencer7593) or else via a second procedure which this procedure invokes.  I can't find any reference to this behaviour in the manual, so I'm inclined to interpret it as a bug.

Comment: Workarounds are not an issue - I wanted to understand the original behavior. `MODIFIER SQL DATA`, `READ SQL DATA` and `NOT DETERMINISTIC` and `mydata.*` does not work either. `FLUSH TABLES` does not work - not surprised considering dropping the table before 2nd execution did not work either. Annoyance really - but I am thinking bug too

Comment: Oh and if the table is dropped before execution of the SP then the `*` expansion is unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is reusing the statement that was prepared on the previous execution.  It's not really "caching" column names; what it's "caching" (if you will) is the prepared statement.

The easy workaround is to use dynamic SQL statement to gain control over the behavior, and avoid the reuse of the previously prepared statement:

```
SET @s=CONCAT('SELECT ',@mycol,' FROM mydata');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

It's not matter of the column names being "cached", or the results of the query being cached. It's a performance optimization; it's a matter of that statement already being prepared, within your session.

---

By using dynamic SQL, you can control when the statement is prepared (i.e. parsing the SQL text for syntax (statement formation, keywords, etc.), checked for semantics (object names exist, column names exist, user has required privileges, etc.), and preparing an execution plan.

With the static SQL, all of that happens on the first execution, and then MySQL hangs on to the prepared statement.

For performance reasons, we wouldn't want the overhead of a "hard parse" every time a static statement is executed. This is especially true on a function that gets called multiple times, from a SQL statement.

(**NOTE:** Oracle does the same thing, BUT, Oracle does a good job of marking prepared statements as INVALID whenever a referenced object is altered or dropped.)

MySQL opted not to do that, probably because of the overhead of tracking all the dependencies. And, in the vast majority of cases, that overhead is not required.

I think the lesson here is if you are going to use dynamic SQL to create a table that is going to have DIFFERENT columns in it, you are going to have to use dynamic SQL to query that table.

---

My recommendation is that you avoid using `SELECT *`, unless your statement is in complete control of the columns being returned, for example, from an inline view. Otherwise, SQL statements that use `SELECT *` are fundamentally broken... they may work now, but a change to a table (adding a column for example) will break an application.

---

**Q:** Please explain how it is not a bug.

It is not a bug because the SELECT statement in your stored procedure is really just shorthand for what is actually happening.

On the first execution of your procedure, MySQL is doing the parse of your query text, and preparing and executing a statement. Basically, equivalent to:

```
PREPARE s1 FROM 'SELECT * FROM mydata';
EXECUTE s1;
```

On the second execution of the procedure, MySQL is simply executing the statement that has been previously prepared. Basically, equivalent to:

```
EXECUTE s1;
```

On that second execution, you seem to be expecting MySQL to run the equivalent of:

```
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
PREPARE s1 FROM 'SELECT * FROM mydata';
EXECUTE s1;
```

You can make a case that this is what MySQL *should* be doing on the second execution. You could argue that statements prepared during a previous execution of a procedure should be discarded, and re-parsed and re-prepared on subsequent executions.

It would not be wrong for a DBMS to do this. But there would be, as always, the consideration about the impact on performance.

You could also make a case that MySQL should track all the database objects that a particular prepared statement is dependent on. You could argue that whenever one of those database objects is dropped or altered, MySQL should invalidate all the prepared statements (and all other objects) that depend on the altered or dropped object. Again, it would not be wrong for a DBMS to do this. Some DBMSs (such as Oracle) do this quite well. But again, the developers of the DBMS also take performance into consideration when making these design and implementation decisions.

The bottom line is that MySQL *does* provide you with a way to make happen what you want to happen. It's just that the syntax in your procedure, what you are expecting to make it happen,  doesn't actually make it happen.

---

**first of all it is a temp table so really should not be expected to be there, 2nd - it is dropped**

I think you are reading something different into the `"TEMPORARY"` keyword than is defined in the specification. A `TEMPORARY` table is really just like a regular table, except that it is visible only to the session that created it, and it will be automatically dropped when the MySQL session ends. (We also note that a `TEMPORARY` table is not displayed by a SHOW TABLES command, and does not appear in the information_schema views.)

As to which tables (TEMPORARY or otherwise) MySQL should expect "to be there", I don't believe the documentation really addresses that, except noting that when a SQL statement is executed, and that statement references an object that does not exist, MySQL will throw an exception.

The same behavior you observe with a TEMPORARY table, you will also observe with a non-TEMPORARY table. The issue is not related to whether the table is defined as TEMPORARY or not.

---

**where does** `SELECT *` **compare to**  `PREPARE s1 FROM SELECT *`

Those two forms effectively follow the same code path. The first execution of a static `SELECT *` is effectively equivalent to:

```
PREPARE s1 FROM 'SELECT *';
EXECUTE s1;
```

(Note the absence of a `DEALLOCATE` statement following the exeuction.) On a subsequent execution, the statement is already prepared, so it's effectively equivalent to:

```
EXECUTE s1;
```

This is similar to what would happen if you were coding in PHP mysqli

```
$s1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM mydata");
$mysqli->execute($s1);
/* rename the columns in the mydata table */
$mysqli->execute($s1);
```

Comment: This is the query that fails though "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM mydata;"

Comment: First execution from a new session always works - so it is session related.

Comment: I disagree with your lesson ;-) IMHO mysql is broken, I'll probably not accept your answer unless this proves to be mysql bug - just because everything you have is a workaround rather than an answer to the original question. But thank you for taking the time to look

Comment: @Adrian: You are free to disagree with the lesson. You are free to believe that "mysql is broken" and that the behavior you observe is a "mysql bug". All sorts of programming languages allow you to write code that compiles but that is broken. In this regard, MySQL is not really any different than any other programming language.

I believe that MySQL is performing to the specification. I believe MySQL is *not* broken, and the behavior you observe is is *not* a bug. It may not be behaving according to your expectations, but your expectation is *not* the specification.

Comment: Please explain how it is not a bug. I drop the temp table and execute the SP for the second time - yet mysql complains a column is missing from the first dropped execution of the table? Is my expectation that DROP TABLE removes the table from the DB wrong?

Comment: I am sorry - where does SELECT * compare to PREPARE s1 FROM SELECT * - The table TEMP table is dropped outside of the SP - first of all it is a temp table so really should not be expected to be there 2nd - it is dropped - in what reasonable world would anyone expect it to be there or that even caching the results is a  good idea. You sound like a junior C programmer saying "well the undefined behavior works". The table was dropped - end of story - nothing should refer to it. Docs say "All table data and the table definition are removed, so be careful with this statement!"

Comment: Linked as same bug as http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61434 - Man you DBA's with deciding what is a feature ;-) compared to what is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is relatively old (+6 months) but I encountered this problem in prepared statements, and the only way I got around it was to concatenate the field names and use a prepared statement that effectively calls "select *" but uses the actual field names.  I'm using prepared statements to create a temporary table, and the only standard field is the first one, while the rest causes the caching problem on "`Select *`".

- Select fields we want to use into a temp table
- Iterate through table rows of field names, and on each iteration:

  set sql01 = concat(sql01,',`',sFieldName,'`'); (just fields) and: set sql02 = concat(sql02,',`',sFieldName,'` varchar(50) '); (fields + field type only, for create table statement)
- create the output table:

  set @sql = concat('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tOutput(FirstField varchar(50), ',sql02,');'); PREPARE STMT FROM @sql; EXECUTE STMT; DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
- At the end:

  set @sql = concat('SELECT FirstField,',sql01,' FROM tOutput;'); PREPARE STMT FROM @sql; EXECUTE STMT; DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;